# How improve my code to get friends in tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy

I wrote a code to pick friends for a list of ids in twitter.
But API issues make this code very slow.
It's possible improve?
My code is:

```
import tweepy
consumer_key = ''
consumer_key_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_key_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

for cara in fin1:
    if cara in dici1.keys(): next
    else:
        amigos=[]
        for user in tweepy.Cursor(api.friends, screen_name=cara).items():
            time.sleep(60)
            try:
                amigos.append(user.screen_name)
                comum = [pessoa for pessoa in amigos if pessoa in fin1]
                dici = {cara : comum}
                dici1.update(dici)    
            except: time.sleep(60), next
```

`fin1` is the list of ids(name of the user, 39 in total)

`dici1` is a dict is where i store the information.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `time.sleep` call, it's not necessary, you also have some stuff that make no sense at all, like those `next`

```
import tweepy
consumer_key = ''
consumer_key_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_key_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

for cara in fin1:
    if cara in dici1 
        continue

    amigos = []
    for user in tweepy.Cursor(api.friends, screen_name=cara).items():
        try:
            amigos.append(user.screen_name)
            comum = [pessoa for pessoa in amigos if pessoa in fin1]   
            dici1[cara] = comum
        except:
            time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: The next is necessary because dici1 has other ids, then i no need re-run. I'm cut the time sleep thing. Thanks!

Comment: @RafaelCamargos the `next` is not doing anything at all, you are definitely misunderstanding how it works, you meant to use `continue`

Comment: Thanks @FranciscoCouzo ! I check the control flow statements `continue` is the command i want.